# How to accelerate ASP MVC site response time

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When I run my ASP MVC site locally, or in the same LAN the response time is immediate.
However on production the response time is considerably slow (2-3 seconds for each request).
When I connect using remote desktop to the server and run the site locally - response time is very good.

For other sites on the same server, response time is good.

What can be done to accelerate ASP MVC site response time?

(I guess that there are several factors)

Comment: Do you use Firebug "network tab" to see which requests takes times ?

Comment: Excellent point by @Massanu, and essential in finding out what resource is causing the block. There is nothing you can do, given the information you've provided, to speed it up as there is not likely a problem with ASP.NET, but more likely your host and/or environment.  Internet Explorer and Chrome also have "Developer Tools" built in, just hit F12 and pop into the network tab to see what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like it's not your code but your web host that's the issue.

[Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/) and [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) might show an issue, but it's probably worth working through the points in [Muhammad Akhtar's SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340218/asp-net-website-slow-performance-on-production-server) first. It looks like the final solution in that post was to upgrade the production server's processor.